# Dictionary functionality to include key in richtext or widget labels

Tags: aem, rich-text-editor

I need to implement a dictionary in AEM — I have created an `i18n->en->sling message` entry with a key-value pair ("gegessen" is the key and message is "Record"), and I am able to render the message value in Sightly using the expression:

```
${'gegessen' @ i18n}
```

If I change the message, it should be reflected in all the locations where I am using key. How can I make this key available in the Rich Text Editor and in widget labels?